# is it possible to do some automatic login without showing the login screen using rest API?

Tags: api, login

I made a REST API to be able to de queries for salesforce, however, I need to be logging in from time to time, my application will be used by different users and this does not have to happen. I have read about doing a refresh and using a refresh_token, but when I want to do that, I get the following message

> No refresh token is stored in the current session. Verify you have
> added refresh_token to your scope items on your connected app settings
> in Salesforce.

and that message shows me every time I try to use my app without logging in to salesforce and authorizing my API.

[image]

using the [omniphx/forrest](https://github.com/omniphx/forrest) library I call the refresh method (refresh token) using         Forrest::refresh(); before the query to try to log in without using the login screen, but that's when I get that message.

I have the consumer key, access_token key and consumer secret

Comment: Step 1: understand what you're doing via plain HTTP requests/responses. Whatever oAuth sequence you're trying to implement, do it with curl or equivalent and without your library. Step 2: if successful, use your library to implement the same sequence.

Comment: @identigral I have already been doing it with cURL and without the library, the problem is that I have to be logging in later, that is what I want to avoid

Comment: Add refresh token to scope and use the [oAuth refresh flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5)

Comment: @identigral should the refresh token be added in OAuth Custom Scopes? Or where?

Comment: scope=`Full access` does not include the refresh token